# OpenCV Cython bridge leaking memory

Tags: python, c++, opencv, cython

I have written an implementation of the `VideoCapture` class that works with Basler cameras. It is used like this:

```
import cv2
import PyBaslerCamera

video = PyBaslerCamera.PyBaslerCamera()
video.open(0)
while True:
    ret, image = video.read()
    cv2.imshow("Test", image)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

My Cython file looks like this:

```
# distutils: language = c++
# distutils: sources = BaslerCamera.cpp

from cython.operator cimport dereference as deref
from cpython.ref cimport PyObject
from libcpp cimport bool

cdef extern from "opencv2/core/core.hpp" namespace "cv":    
    cdef cppclass Mat:
        bool empty() const
        void release() const

    cdef cppclass _OutputArray:
        Mat getMat(int idx=-1) const



cdef extern from "cv2.cpp":
    void import_array()
    PyObject* pyopencv_from(const Mat&)
    int pyopencv_to(PyObject*, Mat&)

cdef Mat np2mat(object array):
    cdef Mat mat
    cdef PyObject* pyobject = <PyObject*> array
    pyopencv_to(pyobject, mat)
    return <Mat>mat

cdef object mat2np(const Mat &mat):
    return <object> pyopencv_from(mat)

cdef extern from "BaslerCamera.h" namespace "cv":
    cdef cppclass BaslerCamera:
        BaslerCamera()
        bool open(int index)
        bool isOpened()
        void release()
        bool grab()
        Mat retrieve()
        bool read(_OutputArray image)
        Mat read()
        bool set(int propId, double value)
        double get(int propId)
        BaslerCamera &operator>>(Mat &image)

cdef class PyBaslerCamera:
    cdef BaslerCamera *thisptr
    cdef Mat mat

    def __cinit__(self):
        print("PyBaslerCamera init")
        import_array()
        self.thisptr = new BaslerCamera()

    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr

    def open(self, int index = 0):
        self.thisptr.open(index)

    def read(self):
        mat = self.thisptr.read()

        if mat.empty():
            return (False, None)
        else:
            out = mat2np(mat)
            return (True, out)
```

And I have used the cv2.cpp file from OpenCV:
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp

Now, everything works, I am getting the video stream from the camera, but the problem is that it leaks a lot (in a couple of seconds it will fill up my ram, which leads me to believe that it just leaks all the frames). Valgrind seems to confirm that

```
==21435== 1,050,624,000 bytes in 152 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 5,939 of 5,939
==21435==    at 0x4C2BBA0: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==21435==    by 0x20D7F3AB: ??? (in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
==21435==    by 0x20D1BD89: ??? (in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
==21435==    by 0x251D55E1: NumpyAllocator::allocate(int, int const*, int, void*, unsigned long*, int, cv::UMatUsageFlags) const (cv2.cpp:156)
==21435==    by 0xB983720: cv::Mat::create(int, int const*, int) (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.0.0)
==21435==    by 0xB9B54C7: cv::_OutputArray::create(int, int, int, int, bool, int) const (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.0.0)
==21435==    by 0xB810A7C: cv::Mat::copyTo(cv::_OutputArray const&) const (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.0.0)
==21435==    by 0x251D44F9: pyopencv_from<cv::Mat> (cv2.cpp:211)
==21435==    by 0x251D44F9: __pyx_f_14PyBaslerCamera_mat2np (PyBaslerCamera.cpp:662)
==21435==    by 0x251D44F9: __pyx_pf_14PyBaslerCamera_14PyBaslerCamera_6read(__pyx_obj_14PyBaslerCamera_PyBaslerCamera*) [clone .isra.9] (PyBaslerCamera.cpp:973)
==21435==    by 0x503F5C: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (in /usr/bin/python3.4)
==21435==    by 0x5A9CB4: PyEval_EvalCodeEx (in /usr/bin/python3.4)
==21435==    by 0x5E7104: ??? (in /usr/bin/python3.4)
==21435==    by 0x5E71C8: PyRun_FileExFlags (in /usr/bin/python3.4)
==21435== 
==21435== LEAK SUMMARY:
==21435==    definitely lost: 165,107 bytes in 262 blocks
==21435==    indirectly lost: 179,724,840 bytes in 205 blocks
==21435==      possibly lost: 1,057,720,529 bytes in 646 blocks
==21435==    still reachable: 9,399,307 bytes in 10,288 blocks
==21435==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21435== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==21435== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
```

It looks like the `ndarray`s created by the Numpy allocator don't get released, but I am at a loss at how to address this. Can anybody tell me how to properly release this memory?

Or if someone has a better suggestion on how to approach this whole `cv::Mat` to `np array` business I'm open to ideas.

Comment: I think (but I'm not 100% sure) that you want to change `PyObject* pyopencv_from(const Mat&)` to `object pyopencv_from(const Mat&)`. I believe that `pyopencv_from` will return something with a refcount of 1, and the cast to object will increase it to 2, but only one will ever be released. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/pZFurj3rUyg

Comment: That was indeed the case! Please post it as a reply and I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was that you needed to change the definition of `pyopencv_from` from `PyObject* pyopencv_from(const Mat&)` to `object pyopencv_from(const Mat&)`:

```
# just illustrated in place
cdef extern from "cv2.cpp":
    void import_array()
    object pyopencv_from(const Mat&)
    # etc

# and a function that appears a bit later...
cdef object mat2np(const Mat &mat):
    # return <object> pyopencv_from(mat) # Problem line!
    # can now become:
    return pyopencv_from(mat)
```

This was based on [a newsgroup post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/pZFurj3rUyg) which references documentation that I think no longer exists. Quoted here:

> whenver the Py_ function returns
>   a *new reference* to a `PyObject*`, the return type is "object".
>   When the function returns a borrowed reference, the return
>   type is `PyObject*`.  When Cython sees "object" as a return type
>   it doesn't increment the reference count.  When it sees `PyObject*`
>   in order to use the result you must explicitly cast to `<object>`,
>   and when you do that Cython increments the reference count wether
>   you want it to or not, forcing you to an explicit `DECREF` (or leak memory).
>   To avoid this we make the above convention.
>
> With borrowed
>   references if you do an explicit typecast to `<object>`, [Cython] generates an
>   `INCREF` and `DECREF` so you have to be careful.

So the gist is:

- The object returned from `pyopencv_from` has a refcount of 1.
- If you tell Cython the function returns `object` it refcounts it appropriately (the generated code will probably show `GOTREF` which is a no-op except for debugging purposes followed by `DECREF` a bit later at which point the memory's freed).
- If you tell Cython the function returns `PyObject*` it does nothing because it just treats it as an arbitrary pointer type (OK - but you then have to do the refcounting)
- When you do the explicit case to `<object>` (see "problem line" in the listing above) it increments the reference by 1 (so it's now 2) to claim ownership, but only ever decrements it once. The reference count stays at 1 forever and the object is never freed.

Comment: Thanks for the exhaustive answer! However just returning directly from `pyopencv_from()` didn't work for me (`Cannot convert 'PyObject *' to Python object`), I had to cast to `<object>` manually and then do a `Py_DECREF()` manually.

Comment: Ah - I think you need to make two changes: return directly, but also change the definition of `pyopencv_from()` in the `cdef extern from "cv2.cpp":` block (don't worry that it doesn't match the header exactly!). However, doing a manual `Py_DECREF()` works too, so if it's working like that then leave it like that.